# Orchard : menu link to specific user

Tags: razor, orchardcms

been some days on developing my own web using Orchard CMS.

I am making a profile that all users can browse and admin can edit.
Just install Profile Package, however, I had no idea how to construct a string that link to myself profile.

localhost:80/profile/"username"

How to link the specific username navigation custom link url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only URL to get to your own profile includes your username.

So, if you want to link to the current user's profile you need to work it out, like this:

```
@if (WorkContext.CurrentUser != null) {
    @Html.ActionLink("your profile", "Index", "Home",
        new { area="Contrib.Profile",
            username = WorkContext.CurrentUser.UserName }, null)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works. P.S. Is this mean I can't use it as a link in nav menu. but I can make a Profile link some where in the Page.  :)

Comment: besides the question What does WorkContext does, what is storing inside? many thanks

Comment: I can't think of a way to add it as a link in a nav menu. WorkContext has lots of useful info in it like CurrentTimeZone, CurrentTheme, CurrentSite, CurrentCulture and CurrentUser. Intellisense in Visual Studio helps to explore.